# Making "Flappy Bird" Game In Unity3D (Flappy Plane), How To Destroy The Obstacles?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am beginner to Unity3D and programming with C#. I am making game called flappy plane. The problem is destroying the obstacles after they go off screen. I made prefab and a code that makes clons of that prefab somewhere on the scene(with instantiate) and of course, that prefab (the obstacle) moves to the left.

I tried using this code:

```
void Update()
{
    Vector2 position = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (transform.position);
    if (position.x < Screen.width)
    {
// Here I will try to destroy the obstacle.
        }
    }
```

This code isn't really logic so please people help me. I've tried doing it but i don't know how can i make the width thing. I want to destroy the obstacles for speeding the game. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `MonoBehaviour.Destroy(gameObject)` what you're after? I'm not really sure what part of the process you are struggling with?

Edit:
With the clarification, below is the revised answer:

Track the position of the players co-ordinates, and when an object finds that its own co-ordinates are less that players co-ordinate minus the offset of where the player is on the screen, destroy it. Basically something like the following (assuming the camera is always centred on the player and moves along with it):

```
void Update()
{
    int xBound = Camera.main.transform.position.x - (Screen.width / 2);
    if (transform.position.x < xBound)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.Destroy(gameObject)
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I know how to do that but the code written up there doesn't work, most likely the if statement is not correct, I have no clue what to do there.

Comment: Edited my answer to suit the question clarification.

Comment: Still doesn't work.. and i don't know if you understood me what i asked.